# C# Custom Json using JSON.NET from dataset or datatable

Tags: c#, json, post, dataset, json.net

Can somebody help me to get the custom JSON string from datatable using C#.

I need something like below.I am able to achive this by using for each loop.

```
[
    {"message": {"alert": "Address Updated"},"target": {"userIds": ["BKAC7759"]}},
    {"message": {"alert": "Payment Processed"},"target": {"userIds": ["BKAC7759"]}},
    {"message": {"alert": "Notice Sent"},"target": {"userIds": ["BKAC7759"]}}
]
```

But is there any way i can make it in simple way. My datatable contains values for "alert" and  "userIds"

```
    private string GetJsonData(int numberofRecords)
    {
        //  OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        try
        {
            DataTable Test = new DataTable("A");
            Test.Columns.Add("alert");
            Test.Columns.Add("userIds");
            Test.Rows.Add("Address Updated", "BKAC7759");
            Test.Rows.Add("Payment Made", "BKAC7759");
            //Test.Rows.Add("Check Processed", "MAND1884");
            //Test.Rows.Add("Notice Mailed", "JAID3869");
            //Test.Rows.Add("DL Suspended", "AOQU4798");
            string jo = string.Empty;
            string com = ",";
            int i = 0;
            int count = Test.Rows.Count;
            string bracketright = "]";
            string bracketleft = "[";
            foreach (DataRow row in Test.Rows)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    jo = jo + bracketleft;
                }
                jo = jo + "{\"message\":{\"alert\":\"" + row[0].ToString() + "\"},\"target\":{\"userIds\":[\"" + row[1].ToString() + "\"]}}";
                if (i != count - 1)
                {
                    jo = jo + com;
                }
                else
                {
                    jo = jo + bracketright;
                }
                i++;
            }
            return jo;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error("GetJsonData(int numberofRecords): " + ex.Message);                
            return string.Empty;
        }
        finally
        {
            // always close the connection.
           // conn.Close();
        }                        

    }
```

Comment: That JSON looks like it corresponds to a single `DataTable` rather than to a `DataSet`. See [Serialize a DataSet](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDataSet.htm).  Can you give a [simple but complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code that creates one of the data sets you want to serialize?

Comment: Yes I am having a data in a single databale. edited the Question and gave sample code which i am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq + [`DataTableExtensions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (in namespace `System.Data` and system DLL `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll`) to transform your table into an enumerable of [anonymous types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx), then serialize that to JSON with [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net).

I notice your `"userIds"` property is a *JSON array*.  Do you want all the user userIds for a given alert to be combined?  If so, you can use [`ToLookup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549211%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to combine them:

```
        var root = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
            .ToLookup(r => r["alert"].ToString(), r => r["userIds"].ToString())
            .Select(g => new { message = new { alert = g.Key }, target = new { userIds = g } });

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root);
```

If not, do:

```
        var root = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
            .Select(r => new { message = new { alert = r["alert"].ToString() }, target = new { userIds = new [] { r["userIds"].ToString() } } });

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root);
```

For the following table:

```
        var dataTable = new DataTable("A");
        dataTable.Columns.Add("alert");
        dataTable.Columns.Add("userIds");
        dataTable.Rows.Add("Address Updated", "BKAC7759");
        dataTable.Rows.Add("Payment Made", "BKAC7759");
        dataTable.Rows.Add("Address Updated", "MAND1884");
        dataTable.Rows.Add("Payment Made", "MAND1884");
```

The first produces the following JSON:

```
[
    {"message":{"alert":"Address Updated"},"target":{"userIds":["BKAC7759","MAND1884"]}},
    {"message":{"alert":"Payment Made"},"target":{"userIds":["BKAC7759","MAND1884"]}}
]
```

And the second produces the following:

```
[
    {"message":{"alert":"Address Updated"},"target":{"userIds":["BKAC7759"]}},
    {"message":{"alert":"Payment Made"},"target":{"userIds":["BKAC7759"]}},
    {"message":{"alert":"Address Updated"},"target":{"userIds":["MAND1884"]}},
    {"message":{"alert":"Payment Made"},"target":{"userIds":["MAND1884"]}}
]
```

Comment: Awesome. I need both of above two scenarios. I will use them. Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help.